# Show one <p> at a time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have below HTML with multiple `<h1>` and after each `<h1>` one paragraph element. I want to display one `<p>` at a time.

**HTML**

```
<h1>Heading One</h1>
<p class="answ 1">This is first paragraph.</p>
<h1>Heading One</h1>
<p class="answ 2">This is first paragraph.</p>
<h1>Heading One</h1>
<p class="answ 3">This is first paragraph.</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function(){

    var heading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
        para = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

        var evtDelegation = function(evt){
            var target = evtUtility.getTarget(evt);

            if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'h1'){
                evtUtility.nextSiblings(target).style.display = 'block';
            };

        };

    evtUtility.addEvent(document, 'click', evtDelegation);

})();
```

Working Example: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bwNu8/)

Comment: are you allowed to use jQuery library?

Comment: no please use only javascript not any library

Comment: ok are you trying to animate the p element? or just simply displaying it one at a time? what triggers the hiding or displaying of the p element?

Comment: It would be great if you can animate it.

Comment: use some jquery libraries : look for panel bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the other `p` tags before opening a new one:

```
var heading = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
var para = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

    var evtDelegation = function(evt){
        var target = evtUtility.getTarget(evt);

        if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'h1'){
            for(var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++){
                paras[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            evtUtility.nextSiblings(target).style.display = 'block';
        };
    };
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bwNu8/2/

Comment: why it's not working with var para = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

Comment: Are you asking why the original didn't work or does the code I have provided not work?

Comment: yes...because I had already tried this for loop...but I use para variable.

Comment: `para` is not an array, so you cannot loop through it, that is why I created `paras` which holds all `p` elements.  `para` is assigned the first `p` element found on the page, so it cannot be iterated through.

Answer (score 0):

```
       if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'h1'){
            /* get all "p" elements*/
            var ps=document.getElementsByTagName("p");
            /* traverse through those elements */
            for(var i=0;i<ps.length;i++){
                /* if any of it has class "answ" hide it*/
                if(ps[i].getAttribute("class").indexOf("answ")!=-1)
                    ps[i].style.display='none';
            }
            evtUtility.nextSiblings(target).style.display = 'block';
        };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bwNu8/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can store a reference to the previously opened paragraph and hide it before displaying a new one. This has the advantage of being quicker if you have lots of paragraphs.

```js
// My function to open and close the p tag

var para = null
var evtDelegation = function(evt){
    var target = evtUtility.getTarget(evt);

    if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'h1'){
        if(para !== null) {
            para.style.display = 'none';    
        }
        para = evtUtility.nextSiblings(target);
        para.style.display = 'block';
    };
};

evtUtility.addEvent(document, 'click', evtDelegation);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dHUPg/